# Define global scope of a variable EJS with node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Here is the snippet.

```
<% console.log('.................. upper count', count); %> //count is undefined...

//data object is getting from node script
<% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %> 
  <tr>
      <td>data</td>
  </tr>
<% var count = i + 1; 
  console.log("................", count); //Here I got count = 2
%>
<% } %>
```

Is there any way to print a value of count at the first line that we have got from the count inside the for loop?

Comment: but you are defining the count variable in the for loop how can you get it in the first line ??

Comment: Though it is not printing value of counter. It will print NULL instead.

Comment: you are not clear in what you exactly want.

Comment: I just want to print the value of count at the first line that is "2" but I got undefined there.  That "2" is getting inside the for loop variable count.

Comment: in the first line count variable is not even defined thats why you are getting undefined, whereas inside the loop you have defined the variable count and its being assigned the value of 2, hence you are seeing 2 in the log

Comment: i tried that but still not printing "2".

Comment: and it wont even print as in the first line its not yet defined, it gets defined in the for loop and gets destroyed in for loop only as it's validity is in for loop's scope only